# How should I solve this using the Frobenius method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

This is the differential equation.

$$ x(x-1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 3x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0 $$

Using the power series method, we get the roots of indical equation to be $0$ and $1$.
Where $ y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+r} $.

The coefficients for $r = 0$ are undefined.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: To be more precise, the recurrence relation for $r_1 = 0$ is $k a_{k + 1} = (k + 1) a_k$, the coefficients are not undefined, but you have to take $a_0 = 0$, which gives a solution linearly dependent on the solution for $r_2 = 1$. Substitute $y(r, x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_k x^{k + r}$ into the ODE and construct the recurrence relation for an arbitrary $r$:
$$(k + r) a_{k + 1} = (k + r + 1) a_k, \\
a_k = \frac {a_0 (k + r)} r.$$
Then the other solution is
$$\lim_{r \to r_1} \frac \partial {\partial r} ((r - r_1) y(r, x)).$$